# How do I combine two Express modules that both require listening to the port?

Tags: node.js, express, cheerio

I am trying to create a web scraper where the user inputs a URL into a form and when they hit submit, the scraper gets the URL and then returns the data about the URL that I specifiy.

My main app.js file is:

```
// Dependencies
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

// Custom Libraries - ./ signals to node not to look in the node_modules directory
var scraper = require('./scraper');

// App.js Variables
var app = express();
var viewsPath = path.join(__dirname, '/app/views');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app/public'));

// set the port - 3000
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

// Form handling
app.use(require('body-parser').urlencoded({
extended:true }));
app.get('/the_test');
// Writes the domain entered in the form to app/data/domain.txt
app.post('/process', function(request, response){
    var domain = request.body.domain;

    fs.writeFile('app/data/domain.txt', domain, function (err) {
      if (err) return console.log(err);
      console.log('Your domain has been saved!');;
    });

    response.redirect(303, '/results');
});

// Routes require
var routes = require('./routes');
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/results', routes);

app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('Express started on http://localhost:' + app.get('port') + '; press Ctrl-C to terminate.');
});
```

My scraper file is:

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

var scraper = express();
// Scrape the url that was posted
scraper.get('/scrape', function(req, res){
  // Scrape this
  var url = fs.readFileSync('./app/data/domain.txt', 'utf8');

  request(url, function(error, response, html){
    if(!error){
      var $ = cheerio.load(html);
      var header;
      var json = { header : ""};

      $('.hero-message').filter(function(){
        var data = $(this);
        header = data.children().first().text();

        json.header = header;

      });
    } else {
      console.log(error);
    }

    fs.writeFile('./app/data/results.json', JSON.stringify(json, null, 4), function(err){
      console.log('File successfully written! - Check your project directory for the output.json file');
    });

    res.send('Check your console!')
  });
});

scraper.listen(4000);
console.log('Magic happens on port 4000');
exports = module.exports = scraper;
```

When I go to localhost:3000, the user is able to enter the URL and hit submit, they are redirected to localhost:3000/results and the URL is logged in data/domain.txt.

When I go to localhost:4000/scrape, the scraper activates, grabs the domain from domain.txt and scrapes it.

My question is how can I make this one fluid program and/or how do I activate the scraper automatically instead of going to localhost:4000/scrape every time? I am very new to Node.js and Express and realize this is a lot of ugly code to look at.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to keep two separate processes for what you are trying to do. What you can do is to move the **scraper** action

```
scraper.get("/scrape", function (req, res) {
    // code
});
```

To the main `app.js` file and serve everything from port `3000`, make sure you include all dependencies from **scraper** on main. At this point, you might want to learn how to use [node's module system](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) to keep code separated and organized.

Depending on how long your scrape process takes, you could do one of the following:

- Change the `process` action to do the work that the `scrape` action does at the moment, so instead writing the domain to a file and then go to a different url to read from that file and start the process, you catch the domain and feed to the scraper right away.
- If the **scraper** takes a long time and you want to start the scrape job automatically, you don't want it to block your application or to throw a timeout during the request. You should consider implementing a worker queue mechanism. There are a lot of ways to do this, and the correct solution depends a lot on the expected use case of your application.